# Conditional probability of picking particular second letters in Scrabble, given the first letter picked

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I was doing a question today and couldn't understand the answer.

Here's the question, my attempt, and the answer:

**Question**

In a game of Scrabble, Dalene has the seven letters A, D, E, K, O, Q and S. She picks two of these letters at random.

Given that she picks the letter Q first, what is the probability that she picks the letter D or the letter K second?

**My attempt**
A = letter Q, B = letter D or K
$P(A) = \frac{1}{7}$
$P(B) = \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$

So my answer is just $P(B) = \frac{1}{3}$

**Official answer**

However, the Correct answer gives $\frac{2}{7}$.

Why is this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Tharindu Thanks for the correction, but it doesn't really answer my question...

Comment: You are asked not for $P(B)$ but rather for $P(B\mid A)$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I thought of that and did P(B|A) = P(AnB) / P(A). P(A), I'm quite sure, is just 1/7, so that would mean that P(AnB) = 2/49. Is it then correct to think of P(AnB) to mean "choosing Q, followed by D/K successively), which would then translate to 2/7 x 1/7 = 2/49?

Comment: are you sure that it is $\frac{2}{7}$? where did you get that official answer

Comment: The only way I get their answer is if the picking is done with replacement (which seems unlikely given what I know of Scrabble). Did they mention that in the original question?

Comment: I'm quite sure - it's at the end of my IB HL math textbook

Comment: @Zimul8r what do you mean by picking is done with the replacement? But as far as details went, this was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: If I chose with replacement, then the chance of pulling a D or a K on the second draw would be 2/7, regardless of the first draw. As it stands, the "Correct" answer looks wrong to me. I'll post an answer an explain...

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll tell you how I solve it, then I'll go into some extra detail on all of the variables you might try to use, just to make everything clear.

As noted by the OP, we're looking for $P(B|A)$. Since the example is given in terms of Scrabble, I am assuming that we're picking 2 tiles from the set, without replacement. In this case, since we're given that the Q is chosen first, there aren't any complex cases where we need to enumerate what happens if a D or a K is chosen first. The Q gets picked, and given that we have 6 remaining tiles to pick from, with 2 of those choices being D and K, the answer is simply $2\over 6$ or $1\over 3$.

Now, if you want to do this more formally, you might decide to use the definition of conditional probability, which states:

$P(B|A) = {P(A\cap B) \over {P(A)}}$.

One problem is that in some cases $P(A\cap B)$ can take a lot of careful counting to compute.  The good news is, this is a small example, and we can actually list all the possible outcomes and count out the results to compute probabilities pretty quickly. There are 7 choices for the first draw, and 6 for the second for a total of 42, and order of draw matters, so here are the possible draws:

AD, AE, AK, AO, AQ, AS,

DA, DE, DK, DO, DQ, DS,

EA, ED, EK, EO, EQ, ES,

KA, KD, KE, KO, KQ, KS,

OA, OD, OE, OK, OQ, OS,

QA, QD, QE, QK, QO, QS,

SA, SD, SE, SK, SO, SQ

So, let's see what our terms are.

$P(A)$ is the # of times Q is drawn first / the total # of draws = 6/42.

We don't use $P(B)$, but for the sake of completeness (and to correct a mistake the OP made), here it is:

$P(B)$ is the number of times a D or a K is drawn second / the total number of draws = 12/42. (which is 2/7, not what the OP had.)

$P(A\cap B)$ is the number of times a Q is drawn first AND a D or a K is drawn second / the total number of draws = 2/42.

$P(B|A) = {P(A\cap B) \over {P(A)}} = {{2/42}\over{6/42}} = {1\over 3}$.

I won't speculate further (as I tried to do in comments) about why the "official" answer the OP was given is listed as 2/7. I assume they made an error, but guessing at which error they made just tends to confuse people (as demonstrated so eloquently in the comments), so I'll stop here.

Comment: I tried it differently, I stayed at the fact that in this case $P(B/A)=P(B)$

Comment: Unfortunately, they're not equal, because B and A aren't independent. That equation only holds when $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B)$, which is only true if they're independent. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)

Comment: @Zimul8r thanks for such a detailed answer - I understand the process now - however, I still don't understand how to differentiate the meaning of the question? How do you know if it is indeed asking for simple probability or a conditional probability?

Comment: Unfortunately, unless a question is posed using rigorous mathematical language, you're forced to interpret in context. As always with word problems, this takes practice so try to encounter as many of these as you can. In this instance, the question specifically refers to things happening first, then second. That's a red flag that you're nearing conditional probability land. If you determine that different outcomes for the first event change the probabilities for the second (in this case picking or not picking a D or K 1st changes your 2nd outcomes), then you're dealing with conditional probs.